# logic constant and physical constness

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Physical constness of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352902/physical-constness-of-a-class)

In C++, regarding an object, what's the difference between logical constness and physical constness?

Comment: Where did you hear these terms?

Comment: The book of "The C++ Programming Language" (page 231). The author gave some explanations, but not that clear, at least to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not standard terms, but I think that "physically constant" would mean a constant object, and "logically constant" would mean a constant reference or pointer.

In the first case, the object is declared constant, `Object const object;`, or is a literal constant such as `1` or `"hello"`, and must never be modified; it is undefined behaviour to do so. The object might be placed in read-only memory to enforce its constancy.

In the second case, the pointer or reference is declared to refer to a constant object, `Object const * pointer;` or `Object const & reference;`, but the object itself is not necessarily constant. The pointer or reference cannot be used to modify the object (unless subverted with `const_cast`), but the object may change by other means if it isn't "physically" constant itself.

Comment: +1, it is important to note that `const_cast` will allow you to write an statement changing the value in both cases, in the second case that is *fine* (by some definition of *fine*) but in the first case it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand those terms correctly the difference is the one between a literal (like `"asdf"` or `1.0f`), being a "physical" constant that might either be substituted during the compilation or saved in a special storage, and a constant variable (`const char*` or `const float`) which is a logical one.

You can't distinguish those in your program and definitely shouldn't try to :)