# C++ Function Const

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class which I am using to try and help understand the concept of const. For example.

```
Class class1:
{
protected:
    double * info;
public: 
    void set(const int i, const int j, const double val) const
    {
          info[i + j] = val;
    }
}
```

I have read multiple articles that say you write const after a class function if that function isn't going to change any member variables. With this class however it works is it correct or incorrect?

Also my understanding of const variables is that you make them const if they are never going to change, but is there any benefit to this?

Thank you, apologies if this has been answered elsewhere i just can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: It's legal code. Whether it's a good idea or not depends on the bigger picture of the class

Comment: You are not changing `this->info`, but `this->info[index]`. That's a huge difference.

Comment: the `const` on the `types` of `class` which mean you have `double*`  then the `const` refers to `pointer` not the `value` ...

Comment: @Kay Are you saying because the function is const it is refering to the pointer?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287497/1505939). Also, [related reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352902/physical-constness-of-a-class/)

Comment: in your case yes it is, if you have another `value` like:`int key`, then `const` refers to value of `key`... and function `set` don't need `const`

Comment: @آدمقنوات This is exactly the explanation i was looking for, clear and i understand it. because info is a pointer it's valid but if not it wouldn't be, thank you. Is there any benefit to declaring const anyway?

Comment: The point of `set` to change `value of members` then you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add some color to already provided answers. Withing `const` qualified functions, all mebers effectively becoming const. For example, your info is becoming const and behaves as if it was defined like this:

```
double* const info;
```

Note, that this IS different from

```
const double* info;
```

First makes info itself unmodifiable (you can't say `info = &d`, but you **can** say `*info = 42`. On the other hand, the later means info is modifieable, but not where it points to. You **can** write `info = &d`, but not `*info = 42`.

Obviously, there is a way to have both qualities, by saying `const double* const info` - that would prevent modifications of both pointer and the value. However, this is not what `const`-qualification does for function. Is it intuitive? I dare say, it is not. However, this is what it is, so we have to live with that.

Obviously, one could argue that const-qualified functions **could** make all member pointers double-const, but what about pointer-like objects (say, `unique_ptr`)? There is no way compiler would be able to make those double const, so it is better to be consistant.

Comment: Thank you, I know it was a simple and stupid question and I appreciate the comprehensiveness of your answer

Answer (score 2):

It is *sort of* correct, a `const` member function doesn't alter internal state.  `set` obviously doesn't alter the pointer `info`, but does alter what it points to.  Now your have to decide (the compiler can't) if this is `const` behavior or not.  In most cases it wouldn't be `const` behavior.

Comment: @RaymondTunstill Pleasure.  If so then please accept this answer, :)

Answer (score 2):

This function *doesn't* change any member variables. The only member variable is `info`, which it doesn't change. It does change *the thing `info` points to*, but that's not a member variable. So it's legal as far as the compiler's concerned.

However, note that it's likely to confuse other programmers (including yourself in six months) - generally, `const` functions *shouldn't* modify the object's state.

Comment: Is a member variable, something like double info; inside the class?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill yes.